# How to avoid public access to private fields?

Tags: c#, .net

For example let's declare:

```
private readonly List<string> _strings = new List<string>();
public IEnumerable<string> Strings
{
    get
    {
        return _strings;
    }
}
```

And now we can do the following:

```
((List<string>) obj.Strings).Add("Hacked");
```

So we're really not hiding the `List` from usage but only hide it behind interface. How to hide the list in such example without copying `_strings` in the new collection to restrict modification of the list?

Comment: Using `IEnumerable<T>` is smart here if your (admirable) goal is to restrict the operations that consumers can perform. Had you decided to return, say, an array instead then you'd be out of luck; you have to make a copy every time.

Comment: @mattytommo: There is no set accessor.  You don't need a set accessor to modify a collection; that's the point of the question.

Comment: @mattytommo: The problem is not that *Strings* is going to change. The problem is that *the object returned by Strings is itself mutable*.

Comment: Dan's answer is good but there are some subtleties here to consider. Suppose for example you hand out a reference to something, and then after you hand out that reference, the contents of the list change due to some *correct* operation inside the class. Is this possible in your scenario? If it is, then does the reference that was handed out earlier need to observe the change? That is, does it behave like an *immutable facade over a mutable collection* or like a *snapshot*, showing the contents of the list as it was in the past?

Comment: Doesn't `ReadOnlyCollection` copy the reference to the list so any changes made to the list will be reflected in the `ReadOnlyCollection`?

Comment: seems it throws an exception when you try to modify

Comment: @SergeyMetlov Leave it as-is, and then on version two of your code, change it from `List<T>` to something like `T[]`, then watch as the cast errors start appearing. This teaches the lesson of coding to the interface (or *public contract*) and not the implementation :-)

Comment: @Romoku: That is correct; `ReadOnlyCollection` acts like an immutable facade; if the intention is to capture a snapshot in time then this isn't a suitable solution. In this case, "readonly" means that **you** can only read it; it does not mean that *it will never change*.

Comment: Eric Lippert discussed the many variations on this question [some time ago](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Plenty of ways.

The most naive approach would be to always copy the private field:

```
return _strings.ToList();
```

But that's not generally necessary. It *would* make sense, though, if:

1. You happen to know that calling code will generally want a `List<T>` anyway, so you might as well give one back (without exposing the original).
2. It's important for the exposed object to hold the original values even if the original collection is subsequently changed.

Alternately, you could just expose a read-only wrapper:

```
return _strings.AsReadOnly();
```

This is more efficient than the first option but will expose changes made to the underlying collection.

These strategies could also be combined. If you need a copy of the original collection (so changes to the original have no effect) but also don't want the object returned to be mutable*, you could go with:

```
 // copy AND wrap
return _strings.ToList().AsReadOnly();
```

You could also use `yield`:

```
foreach (string s in _strings)
{
    yield return s;
}
```

This is similar in efficiency and trade-offs to the first option, but with deferred execution.

Clearly, the key thing to consider here is how your method is actually going to be used and what functionality, exactly, you mean to be providing with this property.

<sub>* Though to be honest, I'm not sure why you'd care.</sub>

Comment: Or using `AsEnumerable()` extension method rather than `yield return`.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` does not copy the values.

Comment: @thecoop `AsEnumerable` just returns the source cast to an `IEnumerable<T>`.  There's nothing stopping a client from casting back to a `List<T>` and adding data.

Comment: You could also use `Select(x=>x)` which will end up creating a new iterator, thus preventing it from being cast back to a `List`.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I thought it did.

Answer (score 7):

How about using a [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx). That should fix that particular problem.

```
private ReadOnlyCollection<string> foo;
public IEnumerable<string> Foo { get { return foo; } }
```

Comment: OP doesn't want people to have access to the list? A `ReadOnlyCollection` still provides read access to the list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that wasn't the problem. If you don't want to expose something publically, you make it private

Comment: I may be mistaken, hopefully OP can provide further clarification.

Comment: Now can the class enclosing `foo` add items to it? I think so, if so, then this answer is wrong, as it changes the internal behavior of the class.

Comment: why does it matter what the "internal behavior" of the class is? What's an implementation detail is an implementation detail. And fyi, no, once a `ReadOnlyCollection` has been created, you can no longer add items to it. That's why its "read-only"

Answer (score 5):

I will just post you my recents thoughts about encapsulation, may be you'll find them reasonable.

As everyone knows, encapsulation is very useful thing, it helps to fight complexicity. It makes your code logically minimalistic and clear.

As you said, protected access to the member can be broken and interface user can obtain full access to the underlying object. But what's the problem with it? Your code will not become more complicated or coupled.

Actually, as far as I know, with usage of some reflection there's almost no restrictions, even with fully private members. So why don't you try to hide them too?

I think there's no need to make a copy of a collection (or any other mutable) and approaches above are wrong. Use your initial variant:

```
private readonly List<string> _strings = new List<string>();
public IEnumerable<string> Strings
{
    get
    {
        return _strings;
    }
}
```

Comment: "and approaches above are wrong" - That's definitely not true, different applications have different needs. If you're making a banking application, you would definitely want to take the pains to make sure people can't just arbitrarily write to your collection.

Comment: @Tejas I always have a theoretical possibility to modify any object in my memory. Espessially, managed. That's why banking applications rely on online authentication, transaction verification etc. rather than specific collection types in their client applications

Comment: well the fact that you can go and modify memory is irrelevant. If you're writing managed code and you would like to provide readonly access to a collection, that seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to do. Agree to disagree I suppose.

Comment: But why create a special collection for it if IEnumerable (or ICollection) interface access is enough? Copying entire collection is even less reasonble. My position is not principal, I just want to understand.

Comment: Because casts are perfectly legal. I agree with you that for MOST cases, simply exposing something as an `IEnumerable` will be good enough. `ReadOnlyCollection` is for those few times when you want the extra protection against modification. That's just how I look at it. It's perfectly reasonable to have conflicting opinions.

Answer (score 3):

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx

> Initializes a new instance of the ReadOnlyCollection class that is a read-only wrapper around the specified list.

Answer (score 3):

you could wrap your list in the getter like so:

```
private readonly List<string> _strings = new List<string>();
public IEnumerable<string> Strings {
  get {
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_strings);
  }
}
```

That way you can freely modify your private list inside your class, and not worry about changes outside.

NOTE: the `ReadOnlyCollection` does not copy the list it contains (e.g. _strings)

Comment: I don't know, maybe they thought that ReadOnlyCollection copies the collection?

Comment: @Tejas - that is incorrect, it does stay in sync with the object

Comment: hmm yeah you're actually right. I suppose it references the actual collection internally. Cool.

Comment: `_strings.AsReadOnly()` performs the same operation as `new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_strings)`, and is arguably a bit cleaner.

Comment: @280Z28 - I agree that your suggestion could be determined to be cleaner. However, my version works on any class that implements `IList`. The `AsReadOnly` method only exists on `List<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Since no one offered this as an answer yet, here's another alternative:

```
private readonly List<string> _strings = new List<string>();
public IEnumerable<string> Strings 
{
    get { return _strings.Select(x => x); }
}
```

It's effectively equivalent to the `yield return` method mentioned earlier, but a bit more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `ReadOnlyCollection` there are truly [Immutable Collections for .NET](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable) available.

Using immutable collections guarantees to the consumer that *collection do not change* rather than just *they cannot change them*. As they're immutable you can just expose them:

```
public ImmutableList<string> Strings { get; private set; }
```

More details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx